# DialogFragment: Dialog opens Sub-Dialog: how can Dialog be notified that Sub-Dialog has finished?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-lifecycle, android-dialogfragment

Given Android 
[TransactionsActivity](https://github.com/MaxIsV/privacy-friendly-finance-manager/blob/feat-49_Add_category_Account_from_transactiondialog/app/src/main/java/org/secuso/privacyfriendlyfinance/activities/TransactionsActivity.java) 
(List of financial Transactions) that opens [AddTransactionDialog](https://github.com/MaxIsV/privacy-friendly-finance-manager/blob/feat-49_Add_category_Account_from_transactiondialog/app/src/main/java/org/secuso/privacyfriendlyfinance/activities/dialog/TransactionDialog.java)

When I press the `add-new-category` button inside the `AddTransactionDialog` the [AddTransactionCategoryDialog](https://github.com/MaxIsV/privacy-friendly-finance-manager/blob/feat-49_Add_category_Account_from_transactiondialog/app/src/main/java/org/secuso/privacyfriendlyfinance/activities/dialog/CategoryDialog.java) opens where i can add a missing category.

Goal: The current Transaction in `AddTransactionDialog` should receive the newly added category after `AddTransactionCategoryDialog` closes.

My Question: How can this be implemented?

Activity and Dialogs use android ViewModell with LiveData

I tried to overwrite the AddTransactionDialog-s `onResume()` method but that method is never called when AddTransactionCategoryDialog closes

Adding a new category works as expected but i donot know how to assign the new category to the current transaction.

For details see

- current ticket: [Allow to add new Category while adding/editing a Transaction](https://github.com/SecUSo/privacy-friendly-finance-manager/issues/49)
- current implementation [in this branch](https://github.com/MaxIsV/privacy-friendly-finance-manager/tree/feat-49_Add_category_Account_from_transactiondialog)